# Is this the right way to move rows from one dataframe to another with a condtion?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to move some rows from `df1` to `df2` when calories in `df1` and `df2` are the same. The two dfs have the same columns.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {
  "calories": [420, 80, 90, 10],
  "duration": [50, 4, 5, 3]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [60, 40, 45]
})

print(df1)
print(df2)



calories  duration
0       420        50
1        80         4
2        90         5
3        10         2
   calories  duration
0       420        60
1       380        40
2       390        45

rows = df1.loc[df1.calories == df2.calories, :]
df2 = df2.append(rows, ignore_index=True)
df1.drop(rows.index, inplace=True)

print('df1:')
print(df1)
print('df2:')
print(df2)
```

Then it reports this error:

```
raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Comment: Do you mean when `calories` are the same for the same index, or if the `calories` value is anywhere in `df2`?

Comment: I mean calories are the same from the same row. For example, '420' are the same for the column calories.

Comment: Do `df1` and `df2` have the same number of rows?

Comment: No. Different rows.

Comment: Actually, it got a problem when they are different rows. My actual data have different  rows. How to fix it? @Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your dataframes are not the same length, you need to use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to find rows with common `calories` values. You need to merge on the `index` and `calories` values; that can most easily be achieved by using [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to temporarily add an `index` column to merge on:

```py
dftemp = df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), on=['index', 'calories'], suffixes=['', '_y'])
```

Output:

```
   index  calories  duration  duration_y
0      0       420        50          60
```

You can now [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the `calories` and `duration` values from `dftemp` to `df2` (using `reset_index` again to reset the index):

```py
df2 = pd.concat([df2, dftemp[['calories', 'duration']]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
   calories  duration
0       420        60
1       380        40
2       390        45
3       420        50
```

To remove the rows that were copied to `df2` from `df1`, we merge just on index, then filter out rows where the two `calories` values are different:

```py
dftemp = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['', '_y']).query('calories != calories_y')
df1 = dftemp[['calories', 'duration']].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
   calories  duration
0        80         4
1        90         5
2        10         3
```

Comment: This works! It is quite complex. Could it be any bug when applying to my real data which  is big?

Comment: @marlon unfortunately it's a difficult problem because the columns are different lengths. But this should work regardless of your data size.

Comment: My data has two more columns, for example, 'A' and 'B'. So 'suffixes=['', '_y']' needs to be changed?

Comment: @marlon rather than selecting columns you want (`dftemp[['calories','duration']]`), you can just delete all the columns ending in `_y` e.g. `dftemp.drop(dftemp.filter(regex=r'_y$'), axis=1)`

Comment: @marlon or you can just add `A` and `B` to the `['calories','duration']` list

Comment: I wrote a loop and it is more understandable. Can you see whether it is right in getting what I want? @Nick

Comment: @marlon no, it doesn't work; `df2.values` looks at the whole dataframe. Try changing the last row of `df2` in your sample data to `390, 80` and you'll see what I mean

Comment: Yes. my code is wrong in logic. Unfortunately, when I apply your solution to my data, it doesn't generate expected result. I added all column names:  just add A and B to the ['calories','duration'], but it doesn't work yet. The fake example worked.

Comment: @marlon if I add columns `A` and `B` to each dataframe and use `dftemp = df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), on=['index', 'calories'], suffixes=['', '_y']); df2 = pd.concat([df2, dftemp[['calories', 'duration', 'A', 'B']]]).reset_index(drop=True)` I get the expected result. I have to go now, I can take another look in the morning if you still haven't got it sorted

Comment: If you add one more row  "A": [420, 4, 5, 3] to df1, it doesn't move it to df2.

Comment: In the end, I found a simpler solution. Please take a look at it in my new EDIT. @Nick

Comment: @marlon I was writing that exact answer at the beginning... but you said in your first comment on the question that you only wanted to match on the same row... Anyway, I'm glad you've got a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {
  "mid": [420, 380, 90, 420],
  "A": [50, 4, 5, 3],
   "B": [420, 4, 5, 3]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {
  "mid": [420, 380, 390],
  "A": [60, 40, 80],
   "B": [150, 24, 25]
})

print('df1:')
print(df1)
print('df2:')
print(df2)
new_df1 = df1[~df1.mid.isin(df2.mid)]

dup_df1 = df1[df1.mid.isin(df2.mid)]
new_df2 = df2.append(dup_df1, ignore_index=True)

print('dup:')
print(dup_df1)
print('df1:')
print(new_df1)
print('df2:')
print(new_df2)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72497406/4) to the question [Is this the right way to move rows from one dataframe to another with a condtion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72497406/is-this-the-right-way-to-move-rows-from-one-dataframe-to-another-with-a-condtion) by the OP [marlon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943868/marlon) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>